# Generate sequence on digits. Sequences should not be any similar

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to generate a long list of 9-digits sequences.

Let's call them ID.

So each ID is unique and the main purpose is to have them all really different. It is unacceptable to have 2 IDs which differs by 1 or 2 digits in sequence.

Do you have any ideas how to implement it without comparing each new generated ID with each previously generated?

Probably there is some algorithm already or simple MYSQL function to compare how close those strings are?

Comment: "...the main purpose is to have them all really different. It is unexceptable [sic] to have 2 IDs which differs by 1 or 2 digits in sequence." *Unique* guarantees they're *really* different. If you want to also guarantee they differ by more than 2 digits in sequence, you guarantee that the sequence is *less* random. See Knuth, vol 2.

Comment: yeah theory vs real life... you did read the question. It is a requirement

Comment: Why not generate a list of 8-digit numbers and add a check digit? That gives you 9 digits and (with a proper algorithm) any single digit change will give you a non-existing number.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, choosing 500,000,000 will knock out {500,000,001; 500,000,002;...; 500,000,099}, {500,000,100; 500,000,110;...;500,000,990}, {500,001,000; 500,001,100;...500,009,900}, and so on. So each value chosen knocks out almost 700 values that differ by one or two digits in sequence. (And that's counting in one direction.) If I'm right about that, your *apparent* search space of 899,999,999 actually consists of less than 1.3 million values, maybe as few as 750,000 values. That's not very many. Try about 100 in sequence to find another valid value (not necessarily in use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following formula for your ID's - you would only need to check that the ID value doesn't already exist in the table (`salt` is a constant between `0` and `100` that doesn't ever change once you pick a value - I would recommend using a prime number, and definitely not `0`):

```
ID = random integer * 101 + salt;
```

This generates ID values like the following (for `salt = 73`):

```
469956305
017775467
001195913
913620520
156482807
577463533
470183959
049290800
078643925
141526626
```

If you take any two of these ID values and compare them, you'll notice that no two numbers differ by only one or two digits in sequence.  I wrote a script to compare all possible ID values between `0` and `3000000`, and there were no two ID values of this form differing by 1 or 2 digits in sequence.  If you want to test it out yourself, here's the script I used (in C#): http://ideone.com/lFHnlX - I reduced the upper limit because of timeout on IDEone.

Comment: I will just mention one additional note.  If your goal is to prevent guessable ID's, please don't let that be a *replacement* for proper access security.  I remember our high school class using an online Java code learning system where the valid user ID's differed by exactly `73`, but there was no code to validate whether you could access a specific record.  I could just keep adding `73` and plugging in different ID values, and I was seeing information about students in other schools and I could have connected with them in the software, even though you weren't supposed to be able to.

Comment: yes the point is this ID is kinda personal access number, so shouldn't be easy guessable like say autoincrement. I know there is a bruteforce and failed attempts will be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get away with not-checking for uniqueness *and* you don't want IDs to be similar? Then you're really looking for [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID)/[GUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID).

[MySQL's built-in `uuid()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) will get you there.

As Robert Harvey points out, UUIDs are alphanumeric (not numeric) and longer than 9 characters, but you're going to have to sacrifice *something* – you cannot satisfy all of your constraints simultaneously.

Comment: Those are not 9 digits, and they contain hex characters. :)  But yes, that was my first thought.

Comment: Indeed. Given the other constraints, I don't see a better option.

Comment: Take a hash or CRC64 of the GUID, and use the first 9 digits.

Comment: There's no way that provides the same statistically-unique "guarantees" as UUID. Programmers can get away with not-checking UUIDs because the value space is so darn large.

Comment: True, but if you're storing them in a "indexed unique" column, you can.  If you generate an identical one, you just generate another one.

Comment: At that point we're no better off than just generating a large random number and letting the DB check & enforce uniqueness. I would consider that a form of "comparing each new generated ID with each previously generated." Like I said in my answer, there's no way to fully satisfy all of the constraints simultaneously. They must be relaxed in some way.

Comment: Yeah, a random number would probably work fine.  The only constraint that is not satisfied is the two-digit thing.  You would have to run some sort of Hamming Distance or Levenshtein calculation against every other number in the database to satisfy that one.  http://www.gmlscripts.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=140